# Selenium click element & Action drag and drop is not working in edge browser using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-edgedriver

Selenium click element & Action drag and drop is not working in edge browser using java
where as same code base works with Chrome & firefox browser without any issue . Facing issue only with edge browser.

Sample Code Snippet :

Driver Setup :

```
                ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver= new ThreadLocal<>();
                WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
                EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
                driver.set(new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions));
```

Click  :

```
        WebElement ele = DriverUtil.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'menu-overlay')]");
        ele.click();
```

Drag & Drop Action :

```
    WebElement ele = DriverUtil.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'b-sch-cell')]");
    Actions action = new Actions(DriverUtil.getInstance().getDriver());
    action.dragAndDropBy(ele, 165, 30).build().perform();
```

Any idea/help/reference link would be much appreciated..

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Need a few more details, what version of Selenium is being used? Provide the imports to the question, that are implemented for setting up for Edge service as well

Comment: @djmonki Thanks for reply .. 
Selenium version : 4.0.0-alpha-5